# UINavigationBar - Set title programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode4, uinavigationbar

I have a tab bar application with a different view on each tab. Each view has a UINavigationBar with title set on Interface Builder. I want to change the title based on a clause in the ViewDidLoad method, so if x { change the title }.

I have tried `self.title = @"title"`, but this changes the title of the tab bar item itself.

So, how is this done?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

I've set the title programmatically using code something like this:

```
navBar.topItem.title = @"title";
```

where navBar is declared as an IBOutlet UINavigationBar linked to the navigation bar in interface builder. This worked in my app; however, I was not using a tab bar.

If navBar.topItem is the tab bar item, I don't see a way for you to change the title that appears on the navigation bar without also changing the title on the tab bar item, since the navBar's topItem and the tab bar item is the same object.

Comment: Worked perfectly, knew I had forgot to do something; and that was link the IBOutlet UINavigationBar to the bar itself. The title and tab text are independent of each other, btw.

Comment: This has a problem, when you have a Back button it changes the title of the back button instead of the navigation bar, check for the response from @CrisP.

Comment: The question was asking about a view that has a UINavigationBar, which is different than a UINavigationController that has view controllers pushed onto it. ChrisP's answer is certainly the right answer in the context of a UINavigationController, but not for the case discussed in the question.

Comment: self.navigationItem.title = @"title"; i believe is the simplest-easiest way

Answer (score 72):

Use

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"the title";
```

as setting `navBar.topItem.title` will not work in all circumstances.

Comment: NB can only used with UINavigationBar associated with a view controller. From the docs ": This is a unique instance of UINavigationItem created to represent the view controller when it is pushed onto a navigation bar. The first time you access this property, the UINavigationItem is created. Therefore, you shouldn’t access this property if you are not using a navigation controller"

Answer (score 25):

Use this :

```
    CGRect navBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 44.0);
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:navBarFrame];

    UINavigationItem *navItem = [UINavigationItem alloc];
    navItem.title = @"Your Title";

    [navBar pushNavigationItem:navItem animated:false];

[self.view addSubView:navBar];
```

or

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = navBar; etc
```

Answer (score 11):

If the class is a type of UIViewController, then you can set title as given in the viewDidLoad method.

```
    [self setTitle:@"My Title"];
```

Comment: This is just, what was causing his problem: it changes the tab bar item's title as well, which was NOT appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Create `IBOutlet` of `UINavigationBar`

```
navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Title";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

**In ViewDidLoad of your ViewController.m just write,**

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"Hello World";
```

Here is the Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I used the following:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Title";
```

However, I also had to call it in a dispatch block as it wouldn't change the title when called within the viewDidLoad w/o it.

Comment: You mention that you also call it in a dispatch block-  This should be included in your exmaple code.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in order for the title to show up AT ALL the Navigation Controller's delegate MUST be set to the navigation bar itself or the title will NEVER show!

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this way in Swift 5

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Title"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just set the title in the ViewDidLoad under your ViewController or TableViewController using

```
_title = @"Title";
```

or

```
self.title = @"Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Your title";
```