# Custom navigation bar doesn't change / show title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I added a `UINavigationBar` in storyboard. My app has to change the title of the bar dynamically. First I tried changing the title in storyboard and ran the app, the title didn't appear. I then tried adding the title by code. First, I connected an `IBOutlet` from the `UINavigationItem` to my `@interface` and tried adding a title like this:

```
_navibarTitle.title = @"Something";
```

It also didn't work out, the title doesn't appear. Since my app has to hide the default bar of the `UINavigationController` and use custom ones, I even tried this:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Something";
```

and this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"HI";
```

they also didn't work out. (the last two i know they wouldn't work as the default navi bar is hidden). So i guess i'm out of ideas. What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you try to NSLog the self.navigationController to make sure it is exist? Or Just try to set the title of the view controller -- self.title = @"your title" which will be displayed as the navigation title if you does not set explicitly.

Comment: @Danyun yes sure i tried NSLoging where the block of code exists and it prints out. So yes it's executing the code

Comment: Set title name of UIViewController which pushed to navigation controller. It will change the title of navigation.

Comment: Danyun isn't asking you to check if it's executing that code block you have above, Danyun is asking if you have actually embedded your UIViewController inside a UINavigationController. You don't manually add UINavigationBar to the interface, that comes with a UINavigationController automatically when you set a root view controller for an instance of UINavigationController. I think he means tried adding this line of code NSLog(@"self.navigationController = %@", self.navigationController);

Comment: you were added the navigation controller for navigation

Answer (score 1):

The simple and best way to set title for a screen or navigation bar is:

`self.title = @"Your Title"`

It will show your title on navigation bar automatically. You can get help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680805/uinavigationbar-set-title-programatically-iphone-sdk-4) question as well.

Other way to do same:

```
    UILabel *navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
    navLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    navLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    navLabel.text = @"Your Title";
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navLabel;
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: yes, this will work, but if you want something custom, like custom color, or custom font, you can't achieve it with this aproach

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
titleLabel.text = @"Something";
[titleLabel sizeToFit];
```